# Create a perfect dashed line with background-image in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I would like to have a dotted line below to a text :

[image]

The web designer have designed a custom dotted so i can’t use :

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 4px dashed #fff;
    display:table;
}
```

because it is not conform.

What i’ve done : I’ve made an image with a dot and position it with css :

```
h2 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display:table;
    background-image: url('../images/tiret.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center bottom; 
}
```

It works very well but depending on the width of the text, the last dot could appear cut like you can see on this picture :

[image]

Do you have a suggestion on how to avoid this ?

Comment: Tell the designer that CSS is not Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use border-image:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
 border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 12px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://yurigor.com/wp-content/images/goldstar.png) 0 0 286 round;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://yurigor.com/wp-content/images/goldstar.png) 0 0 286 round;
-o-border-image: url(http://yurigor.com/wp-content/images/goldstar.png) 0 0 286 round;
border-image: url(http://yurigor.com/wp-content/images/goldstar.png) 0 0 286 round;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/ObLKOo)

Also there is usefull [online generator](http://www.border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fyurigor.com%2Fwp-content%2Fimages%2Fgoldstar.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Afalse%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C33%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C286%2C0%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Afalse%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22round%22%2C%22round%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A0.5520094562647754%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D)

Comment: I like this solution. Works very well.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [background-repeat:space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

> The image is repeated as much as possible without clipping. The first
>   and last images are pinned to either side of the element, and
>   whitespace is distributed evenly between the images. The
>   background-position property is ignored unless only one image can be
>   displayed without clipping. The only case where clipping happens using
>   space is when there isn't enough room to display one image.

Comment: The definition of `background-repeat:space` is what i’m searching for. I’ve noticed it works on Firefox but not on Safari in my case. Need to check what is going on.