# Repeat a linear gradient (as background-image or border-image) an integer number of times

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients, border-image

Is it possible to achieve something like `background-repeat: space` and/or `background-background: round` when using a repeated gradient either as a `background-image`, or `border-image-repeat: space|round` when using a repeated gradient as a `border-image` in browsers besides FF?

This was inspired by [Create a perfect dashed line with background-image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404709/create-a-perfect-dashed-line-with-background-image-in-css), which asks for a way to have a dashed line without partial dashes at the end. In that case, the `background-image` was an image file, so `background-size: repeat` or `background-repeat: round` will work (depending on the exact needs).

But I can't get that to work with a `linear-gradient` or `repeating-linear-gradient` as `background-image` or  `border-image`. Just a couple examples:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#linear-gradient-background-image {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: 28px 8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 75%, transparent 0%);
  background-repeat: round no-repeat;
}
#repeating-linear-gradient-border-image {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 0 solid #000;
  border-bottom-width: 8px;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000 21px, transparent 22px, transparent 28px) 1;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<div id="linear-gradient-background-image">
  linear-gradient background-image
</div>

<div id="repeating-linear-gradient-border-image">
  repeating-linear-gradient border-image
</div>
```

The first example (`#linear-gradient-background-image`) works in FF. But otherwise, there are widths at which a partial dash is drawn at the right hand edge of the `div`.

In webkit browsers, the `#linear-gradient-background-image`'s dash can be seen doing some sort of adjustment when the container is resized, but I'm not sure what it's doing and whatever it is isn't what I'm hoping for.

Comment: The first case works on Firefox.

Comment: Oh I did test FF but must have introduced some fix without noticing. Thanks @Oriol. Still looking for IE and webkit, then